# create a function that accepts an integer and generates an array containing pairs of integers [a, b] sorted by increasing values of a and then b

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, sub-array

I've gotten stuck on this practice problem in my software engineering bootcamp, and am hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

Write a function generatePairs that accepts an integer and generates an array containing the pairs of integers [a, b]. The pairs should be sorted by increasing values of a then increasing values of b.
here are some examples of what should be returned for different inputs:

```
generatePairs(3) // [ [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3] ]
generatePairs(2) // [ [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2] ]
generatePairs(1) // [ [0, 0], [0, 1], [1,1]]
generatePairs(0) // [ [0, 0]]
```

and here is my code so far:

```
function generatePairs (num){
  array = [];
  // 0 [0,0] [0,1]

  // 1

  // 2
  for (i = 0; i<=num; i++){
    array.push([i,i]);
    if ((i+1)<=num) {
        array.push([i,i+1])
    }

    if ( num - i <= num && i===0 && num < i ) {
      array.push([i,num])
      if (num + i < i) {
        array.pop();
      }
    }

  } 
  return array;
}

generatePairs(2) // [ [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2] ]
```

the issue I'm running into is that, for example, when I try it out with 2, I'm missing the [0,2] subarray. The methods I've tried to work around this have mostly consisted of additional if and else loops, but with each one I've tried I either end up with subarrays at the end that go higher than they should, or a semi-working system that would only work for 2 and not for any number that could be inputted into the function.

Comment: Hey! Looking into your code now but for future reference, use `var/let` when defining your variables to avoid a load of bug searching in the future.

Comment: changed  my answer to ninja code  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it much simpler than that?

```js
function generatePairs(num) {
  let arr = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
    for (let j = i; j <= num; j++) {
      arr.push([i, j])
    }
  }
  return arr
}
console.log(generatePairs(2));
```

Comment: 3 `{` and only 2 `}` , and bad second loop... your code is wrong

Comment: Yeah, my firefox crashed while typing so I wrote from phone. Need to edit once on laptop again.

Comment: Lol, realized after editing how wrong it was haha. Never typing from phone again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want right here. You loop through num for the first part until you get to num and for each first part loop from that first part to num.

```
function generatePairs(num) {
    var output = []

    for (var i = 0; i < num + 1; i++) {
       for (var k = i; k < num + 1; k++) {
          output.push([i, k])
       }
    }

    return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution: *(ninja code)*

```js
const generatePairs = n => Array.apply(null,{length:((n+1)*(n+2)/2)}).reduceRight((a,c,i)=>{
  a.r.push([...a.p])
  if(++a.p[1]>n) a.p[1]=++a.p[0]
  return i?a:a.r
},{p:[0,0],r:[]})

for (let x=4;x--;) document.write(x,'->',JSON.stringify(generatePairs(x)), '<br>')
```

Answer (score 0):

**recursion**

We can implement `generatePairs` in an wishful way -

```js
const generatePairs = (n = 0) =>
  chooseN(2, range(0, n))
```

`range` is a simple function that generates an array from `a` to `b` -

```js
const range = (a = 0, b = 0) =>
  a > b                          // base
    ? []
    : [ a, ...range(a + 1, b) ]  // inductive: a <= b
```

and `chooseN` is a generic that generates all `n`-sized samples from array `a` -

```js
const chooseN = (n = 0, a = []) =>
  n <= 0                 // base
    ? [[]]
: a.length <= 0          // inductive: n > 0
    ? []
: chooseN(n - 1, a)      // inductive: n > 0, non-empty a
    .map(r => [a[0], ...r])
    .concat(chooseN(n, a.slice(1)))
```

See `generatePairs` working in your own browser below -

```js
const range = (a = 0, b = 0) =>
  a > b
    ? []
    : [ a, ...range(a + 1, b) ]

const chooseN = (n = 0, a = []) =>
  n <= 0
    ? [[]]
: a.length <= 0
    ? []
: chooseN(n - 1, a)
    .map(r => [a[0], ...r])
    .concat(chooseN(n, a.slice(1)))
    
const generatePairs = (n = 0) =>
  chooseN(2, range(0, n))
    
const log = x =>
  console.log(JSON.stringify(x))
  
log(generatePairs(3))
// [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[2,3],[3,3]]

log(generatePairs(2))
// [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2]]

log(generatePairs(1))
// [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1]]

log(generatePairs(0))
// [[0,0]]
```

---

**generators**

Because combinatorial problems typically involve big solution spaces, it's common to generate combinations lazily. In JavaScript, we can do this using generators -

```js
const chooseN = function* (n = 0, a = [])
{ if (n <= 0)
    return yield []

  if (a.length <= 0)
    return

  for (const r of chooseN(n - 1, a))
    yield [a[0], ...r]

  yield* chooseN(n, a.slice(1))
}
```

Notice the structurally similarity between this program and the one above -

```js
const chooseN = function* (n = 0, a = [])
{ if (n <= 0)                         // if (n <= 0)
    return yield []                   //   return [[]]

  if (a.length <= 0)                  // else if (a.length <= 0)
    return                            //   return []

                                      // else return: 
  for (const r of chooseN(n - 1, a))  //   chooseN(n - 1, a).map(r =>
    yield [a[0], ...r]                //     [a[0],...r])

  yield* chooseN(n, a.slice(1))       //   .concat(chooseN(n, a.slice(1)))
}
```

For example, we could write a `solver` that finds the first pair, `[ a, b ]` where `a > 3` and `3*a` is equal to `2*b`. Critically, no pairs will be generated after the first solution is found -

```js
const solver = (size = 0) =>
{ for(const [a, b] of generatePairs(size))
    if (a > 3)
      if (3 * a === 2 * b)
        return [a, b]
}

console.log(solver(10))
// [ 4, 6 ]
```

And the solution `a = 4`, `b = 6` is correct: `4 > 3` is true and `3*4` is equal to `2*6` (`12`).

Below, we can generate the entire array of pairs, if we wish, using `Array.from` -

```js
const allPairs =
  Array.from(generatePairs(3)) // <-- Array.from exhausts an iterable

console.log(allPairs)
// [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[2,3],[3,3]]
```

Expand the snippet below to generate pairs using JavaScript's generators -

```js
const range = (a = 0, b = 0) =>
  a > b
    ? []
    : [ a, ...range(a + 1, b) ]
    
const chooseN = function* (n = 0, a = [])
{ if (n <= 0)
    return yield []
    
  if (a.length <= 0)
    return
    
  for (const r of chooseN(n - 1, a))
    yield [a[0], ...r]
    
  yield* chooseN(n, a.slice(1))
}

const generatePairs = (n = 0) =>
  Array.from(chooseN(2, range(0, n)))
    
const log = x =>
  console.log(JSON.stringify(x))
  
log(generatePairs(3))
// [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[2,3],[3,3]]

log(generatePairs(2))
// [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,2],[2,2]]

log(generatePairs(1))
// [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1]]

log(generatePairs(0))
// [[0,0]]
```